# Scan subversion repository for active branches

Tags: svn

I have a dozen projects in the repository. The repository structure looks like below:

```
/ -------
   + project1 
       +------- trunk
       +------- tags
       +------- branches
   + project2
```

Our policy requires any active branch to be deleted after 30 day inactivity. However, there is no automatic to detect such branch. Occasionally I have some branch left out for too many days.

Is there a script to list branches, as well as their last check in date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually wrote a script to do it. For those who are interested, you can achieve this through a one liner

```
svn list -v REPO_URL | grep -E "\/branches\/[0-9a-zA-Z_.-]+\/$"
```

My repository is quite big so that this one liner runs too slow. I had to optimize the script not to step into tags and trunk, and not go more than two levels deep.

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried:

```
svn ls -v http://your.svn.server/path/branches
```

That will print the branches with the last revision that affected them, the user and the date.

Comment: This was helpful. Then I found myself wanting to sort by author or date. And I found that I could do it in TortoiseSVN's Repo Browser by pressing F5: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-repobrowser.html

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd do it is I'd write a script to get a list of all branches and then for each branch, get the most recent commit using "svn log -l 1 -q" (Show only the last commit and be quiet about it), parse the date and do some date math.  I don't know of any script/tool that already does this but the approach should work regardless of your branching patterns.